# There is data conversion error in my text_based music player program

Tags: ruby

In the function read_genre Which display the available genre in a list (that I defined 9 different genres inside $genre_name =[] outside of the function) and prompt the user to select a genre by using a case statement and then read in the genre number that user entered a number. The read_genre function is called from the read_album function and then printout in print_album function.

The problem is that after I run the program in the terminal when I prompt to select a genre and entered the number and I get an error  'no implicit conversion from nil to integer (typeError).

I tried by changing the conversion type to to_i(int) and still get the error.

```
module Genre
  POP, CLASSIC, JAZZ, ROCK, KPOP, METAL, PUNK, ROMANCE, LATIN = *1..9
end

$genre_names = ['Null','Pop', 'Classic', 'Jazz', 'Rock', 'KPop', 'Metal', 'Punk', 'Romance', 'Latin']

class Album
    attr_accessor :title, :artist, :genre

    def initialize (title, artist, genre)
        @title = title
        @artist = artist
        @genre = genre
    end
end

# Display the genre names in a
# numbered list and ask the user to select one
def read_genre()
    length = $genre_names.length
    index = 0
    print $genre_names
  while (index < length)
    select_genre = read_integer_in_range("Select Genre: ", 0,9)
        case select_genre
        when 1
        puts "#{index + 1} " + $genre_names[1]
        break
        when 2
        puts "#{index + 2 } " + $genre_names[2]
        break
        when 3
        puts "#{index + 3} " + $genre_names[3]
        break
        when 4
        puts "#{index + 4} " + $genre_names[4]
        break
        when 5
        puts "#{index + 5} " + $genre_names[5]
        break
        when 6
        puts "#{index + 6} " + $genre_names[6]
        break
        when 7
        puts "#{index + 7} " + $genre_names[7]
        break
        when 8
        puts "#{index + 8} " + $genre_names[8]
        break
        when 9
        puts "#{index + 9} " + $genre_names[9]
        break
         else
          puts 'Please Select again'
          break 
        end

    end

end


def read_album
  album_title = read_string("Enter Title: ")
  album_artist = read_string("Enter Artist name: ")
  album_genre = read_genre()
  album = Album.new(album_title, album_artist, album_genre)
  album
end

def print_album album
    puts ' Album information is: '
    puts "Title is #{album.title}"
    puts "Artist is #{album.artist}"
    puts 'Genre is ' + album.genre.to_s
    puts $genre_names[album.genre]

end

def read_integer_in_range(prompt, min, max)
    value = read_integer(prompt)
    while (value < min or value > max)
        puts "Please enter a value between " + min.to_s + " and " + max.to_s + ": "
        value = read_integer(prompt);
    end
    value
end

def main
  puts "Welcome to the music player"
    album = read_album()
    print_album(album)
end

main
```

When I entered the number for the specific genre index. for example, if I entered 2 it must display Classic because it is in index 2 in $genre_names variable.

Comment: Without seeing the code for *read_integer_in_range("Select Genre: ", 0,9)*, seems like that is where the issue might be

Comment: @NeilD'souza just now I add the read_integer_in_range function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think your read_integer(prompt) function should be something like this ...

```
def read_integer(prompt)
  print(prompt)
  gets.strip().to_i
end
```

gets.strip() -> this will return a string like for eg. "2"

"2".to_i -> this then converts from a String to an Integer

This should return an Integer and then you are off to the races.

Hope this helps.